# IE div width issue

Tags: html, css

I have issue with div width in IE,

```
<div style="width: auto;"></div>
```

When I use this code in Firefox it runs ok. But When I run this code in IE it doesn't work any more. Any 1 have any clue? or Is there any other way 2 do it?

Please

Comment: auto has no meaning if the divison has got nothing. Besides what is not happening in IE.

Comment: have you set some CSS properties for div elements in your CSS file ??